# Restarting the apache tomcat services using powershell script

Tags: powershell

I am doing an automation using powershell script to automaticlly start apache tomcat services if it goes down. But the code is not working as expected. Please find the code below :

```
$serviceName = "AGTtomcat7w"
$serviceNamePath = "D:/Pipeline_AGT/apache-tomcat-7.0.82/bin/startup.bat"

$service = Get-Service | Where-Object { $_.Name -eq $serviceName }
write-host "Service Status is" $service.status

if ($service.status -eq "Running") {
   $smtpServer = "161.99.65.10"
   $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
   $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

   $dateString = get-date

   $msg.From = "noreply@example.com"
   $msg.To.Add("abc@xyz.com")
   $msg.subject = "Web services Monitoring"
   $msg.body = ([string]$dateString) + " AGT Maxavera Service" + " is " + $service.status 
   $smtp.send($msg)
}

else {
   write-host "Sending waring email"

   $smtpServer = "161.99.65.10"
   $msg = new-object Net.Mail.MailMessage
   $smtp = new-object Net.Mail.SmtpClient($smtpServer)

   $dateString = get-date

   $msg.From = "noreply@example.com"
   $msg.To.Add("abc@xyz.com")
   $msg.subject = "Service " + $service + " is " + $service.status
   $msg.body = ([string]$dateString) + " AGT Maxavera Service " + " is " + $service.status 
   $smtp.send($msg)

   #Starting the service   
   Restart-Service $serviceNamePath -force

}
```

Can somebody please help me

Comment: I don't see any path parameter for `Restart-Service`, only `-Name`. 
Try `restart-service -Name $serviceName` instead.

Comment: How do you define "the code is not working as expected"? What is it that you expect the code to do?

Comment: @bluuf, it should restart the service if it goes down. But it's not restarting

Comment: @SagePourpre, I am getting below error while running the code : Cannot open AGTtomcat7w service on computer 
'.'.

Comment: why even use `Restart-Service` if you have a batch file? Just run `& $serviceNamePath`.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change $serviceNamePath to $serviceName. Restart-Service wants the name of the service it should restart, not a file path.

```
Restart-Service $serviceNamePath -force

Restart-Service $serviceName -force
```